# Implementing path constraints for Moveit in python

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 6 DOF arm and it has been interfaced with moveit. Now I want to move the arm from  point A to point B with one of the joint having a `orientation constraint` throughout the path. There are already solutions in C++ but I need a solution in `python`. Has anyone already tried in python? Kindly help me to move ahead.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249666/implementing-path-constraints-for-moveit-in-python/) by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 243 on 2016-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on 2016-12-12**:
hi. did u made manipulator by ur own or bought standard one???

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-12**:
I made a manipulator on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `MoveGroupCommander` (one of the python classes for interfacing with MoveIt) provides a `set_path_constraints` function that should set the constraints for the next planning performed through that class.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2016-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-12**:
I had a look at that but do you have any sample code implemented that previously.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2016-12-12**:
I'm not aware of tutorial code that demonstrates this, no.
You are invited to contribute some [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials). :-)